# Error al momento de escribir un audio .WAV

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.7

Hola estoy tratando de extraer audio de una imagen, ya extraje la información de las imagenes pero al momento de crear el audio me genera error. Algún consejo que me puedan dar.

```
import matplotlib.image as mpimg
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.io.wavfile import write

def Img2Audio(Arreglo1,Arreglo2):
      for i in range(len(Arreglo1)):
            for j in range(0,1919):
                  x1 = imgR[i,j]
                  x = Arreglo2.append(x1)

img=mpimg.imread('imagen.png')
imgR = img[:,:,0]
imgG = img[:,:,1]
imgB = img[:,:,2]

AudioL = []
AudioR = []

Img2Audio(imgR,AudioL)
Img2Audio(imgG,AudioR)

Audio = [AudioL,AudioR]

write('test.wav',44100,Audio)
```

Este es el Error:
write('test.wav',44100,Audio)
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'dtype'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bienvenido,

**Aclaración:**

Podrías especificar a qué te refieres con extrar audio de una imagen? Una imagen, a diferencia de un video, **no contiene audio** y según tu código lo que intentas es, a partir de la matrix tridimensional de una imagen ([anchura, altura, color]) usas dos colores para **generar** dos canales de audio. Adicionalmente, la tasa de muestreo es un valor elegido por ti a 44100sps y es determinante en cómo va a sonar dicho audio.

**Solución:**

La solución a tu poblema reside en que la función **write** recibe argumentos tipo (*string, int ,ndarray*) (fuente https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.io.wavfile.write.html) y tu le estás dando un array en lugar de un *ndarray*. El **ndarray** es un objeto de **numpy** que tiene el atributo **dtype** que describe el tipo de dato que contiene el ndarray (que debe ser único entre float32, float64, int8, int16, ... fuente: https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.html). Para solventar tu error guarda los datos que lees de la imagen en un objeto tipo ndarray y funcionará. tu código quedaría algo parecido a esto:

```
import matplotlib.image as mpimg
from scipy.io.wavfile import write
import numpy as np

img=mpimg.imread('imagen.png')

AudioL = np.reshape(img[:, :, 0], newshape=img.shape[0]*img.shape[1])
AudioR = np.reshape(img[:, :, 1], newshape=img.shape[0]*img.shape[1])

Audio = np.array([AudioL, AudioR], dtype=np.float32)

write('test.wav', 44100, Audio.T)
```

Ahí puedes ver que símplemente leo la imagen y después hago un reshape de cada array 2-D de color para dejarlo como un array 1-D, finalmente constreuyo un *ndarray* con cada canal de audio y lo traspongo porque write necesita un ndarray de dimensiones (número de muestras, número de canales).

Comment: Vale muchas gracias por la ayuda, me referia que tenia que extraer el audio de una imagen, el cual la imagen tiene el audio codificado